# Pandas - Dynamically Generating Values in a Column and using them in next rows in Real-Time

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

```
Date          Score    Duration_Diff

2019-05-11     25         0
2019-05-14     30        0.1
2019-06-19     20        1.01
2019-07-23     56        1.04
```

The `Duration_Diff` column is in months. Now I'm multiplying a time decay factor so as to update the scores. However I want to use the updated score in real time and use it in the next row.

For ex.: For index 1 since we don't have any previous date, it will remain the same. For index position 2, lets say I multiply a factor `e^-0.1` to 25, so the updated score becomes `(25*e^-0.1+30)/2=26.3`. Now for Index position 3 I want to multiply the time factor with 26.3 and not with 30 and similar for the other following rows.

The code that I have now considers the static value that is there in the previous row and not the dynamically updated one. I'm not able to come up with a logic that considers the dynamically updated values in real-time so I need some help on how can I use them for the next row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest use [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/) for improvement performance of loops:

```
from numba import jit
import math

@jit(nopython=True)
def func(a):
    for i in range(1, a.shape[0]):
        a[i] = (a[i-1, 0] * math.exp(-a[i, 1]) + a[i, 0]) / 2
    return a[:, 0]

df['score'] = func(df[['score','dur']].values)
print(df)
       score   dur
0  25.000000  0.00
1  26.310468  0.10
2  14.791386  1.01
3  30.614042  1.04
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'score':[25,30,20,56],'dur':[0,0.1,1.01,1.04]})

for i in range(len(df)):
    if i!=0:
        print(df['score'][i-1])
        df['score'][i] = (df['score'][i-1]*math.exp(df['dur'][i])+df['score'][i])/2

print(df)
```

Output:-

```
   score   dur
0     25  0.00
1     28  0.10
2     48  1.01
3     95  1.04
```